# checking for a set of string in a text file android

Tags: android, file, bufferedreader

I am trying to check if all of the strings in `tr` are present in file output. If not then I should return `true` so that I can notify the user, but something is wrong: I am getting the notification again and again even if all strings are present in the file .

```
 public boolean checkinfile(File output, String[] tr) throws IOException {
    Boolean flag = false;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(output));
    String read = br.readLine();
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < tr.length; x++) {
        if ((read.contains(tr[x]))) {

        }
            else {
            flag = true;
            return flag;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code : your code read only the first line of `file` , in my suggestion , when it reads the file , if a `string` not present in the file ,`break` the `loop` of reading and return `true`:

```
 public boolean checkinfile(File output, String[] tr) throws IOException {
    Boolean flag = false;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(output));

    for (int x = 0; x < tr.length; x++) {
        String read = br.readLine();
        if (!(read.contains(tr[x]))) {
            flag=true;
            break;
        }
    }
     return flag;

}
```

Comment: I tried this one but now even the notifications have stopped I din't get the logic behind writing that 'br.readLine()' inside the loop if my text file consists of a single line only

Answer (score 0):

You're only reading the first line of the file.  You need to loop reading all the lines.

Comment: actually there is only one line in my file no escape characters have been used